# cygwin bash completion if you only know the end of a file's name

Tags: bash, cygwin, bash-completion

I cannot figure out how to make a particular type of bash completion work - I am using GNU bash 4.4.12(3)-release, from cygwin.

The completion I am interested in is when you know the end of a file's name but not the start. For example, if the filename is ABC1103.txt, and all you remember is that it ends in '03.txt', you should be able to type ...

```
    ls -l *03.txt<TAB>
```

... and have that expanded to...

```
    ls -l ABC1103.txt
```

it works for completion at an empty bash prompt. For example, if I have a directory 'def1202' under my current working directory, then I can successfully complete the directory name ...

```
    *1202<TAB>
```

.. becomes ...

```
    def1202
```

.. Yet it does NOT work for builtins (e.g., echo) or external commands (e.g. /bin/echo). For example, all of these fail to expand...

```
    % which echo
    echo is a shell builtin
    % echo *03.txt<TAB>
    % /bin/echo *03.txt<TAB>
    % strings *03.txt<TAB>
```

note: there is no 'ls' completion file in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions. But /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/strings does exist.

Comment: it would work by default. did you remove all custom autocomplete rules with `complete -r` and try?

Comment: Your suggestion did indeed re-enable the completion I was attempting to make work (!!!)